# Not Able to access ng-model value in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having a code in which I am trying to access the ng-model values inside the angular controller but getting `undefined` everytime I am trying to call the ng-model value.

**Code**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.phoneNumberValidation = function(phoneNumber) {
    if ($scope.phoneIsVisited == false) {
      $scope.phoneIsVisited = true;
    }

    if (!isNaN(phoneNumber) && phoneNumber.length === 11) {
      $scope.phoneNumberErrorShow = false;
      $scope.pincodeErrorshow = false;
      $scope.phoneNumbervalid = true;
    } else if ($scope.postCodeIsvisited) {
      console.log("went till here");
      console.log(phoneNumber);
      if (!phoneNumber === undefined) {

        console.log("inside else");
        $scope.phoneNumberErrorShow = true;
        $scope.phoneNumbervalid = false;

      } else {

        $scope.phoneNumberErrorShow = true;
        $scope.pincodeErrorshow = true;
        $scope.phoneNumbervalid = false;
      }
    }

  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" minLength="10" maxLength="11" data-ng-model="phoneNumber" data-ng-blur="phoneNumberValidation(phoneNumber)" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" data-sly-test=${!properties.phoneno} placeholder="Phone number" />
  <input type="text" minLength="10" maxLength="11" data-ng-model="phoneNumber" data-ng-blur="phoneNumberValidation(phoneNumber)" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" data-sly-test=${properties.phoneno} placeholder="${properties.phoneno}" />
  <span class="error_msg" data-ng-show="phoneNumberErrorShow">Please enter a valid phone number</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you are passing phoneNumber in function calls?

Comment: Actually I was not able to get the value inside the controller directly by using  $scope.phoneNumber as it was giving undefined to me.

Comment: With the same code I'm able to get phoneNumber. I don't see any issue with accessing the variable.

Comment: @nagaveerGowda Can you please share the pluker code or fiddle for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the minlenght and maxlength conditions you have set in your inputs.

So unless the model value reaches those limit they never would be reflected/bonded to the model value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akhil it worked liked charm. This is funny that model does two-way bind unless they are crosing the min length criteria

Answer (score 0):

phoneNumber needs to be in the scope.

So Set it as $scope.phoneNumber instead of setting phoneNumber in param of the function.

#### UPDATE

In the controller, before the function, set $scope.phoneNumber = null;
Remove the phoneNumber param of the function and replace all phoneNumber to $scope.phoneNumber.

In the view, remove the param when you call the function.

Comment: can you elaborate while calling or in the controller function?

Comment: even after defining null and setting the parameters I am getting the same problem of undefined. I want to state that this field is inside the form element and also, that undefined part is gving me the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the problem with IF conditions. It is not going inside else if statements. Check whether "`$scope.phoneIsVisited`" variable is true before do validations

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.phoneNumberValidation = function(phoneNumber) {

   //Alert if it is defined
    if (phoneNumber !== undefined) {
      alert("Phone Number:" + phoneNumber);
    }
    if ($scope.phoneIsVisited == false) {
      $scope.phoneIsVisited = true;
    }

    if (!isNaN(phoneNumber) && phoneNumber.length === 11) {
      $scope.phoneNumberErrorShow = false;
      $scope.pincodeErrorshow = false;
      $scope.phoneNumbervalid = true;
    } else if ($scope.postCodeIsvisited) {
      console.log("went till here");
      console.log(phoneNumber);
      if (phoneNumber !== undefined) {
        alert("Phone Number:" + phoneNumber);
        console.log("inside else");
        $scope.phoneNumberErrorShow = true;
        $scope.phoneNumbervalid = false;

      } else {

        $scope.phoneNumberErrorShow = true;
        $scope.pincodeErrorshow = true;
        $scope.phoneNumbervalid = false;
      }
    }

  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" minLength="10" maxLength="11" data-ng-model="phoneNumber" data-ng-blur="phoneNumberValidation(phoneNumber)" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" data-sly-test=${!properties.phoneno} placeholder="Phone number" />
  <input type="text" minLength="10" maxLength="11" data-ng-model="phoneNumber" data-ng-blur="phoneNumberValidation(phoneNumber)" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" data-sly-test=${properties.phoneno} placeholder="${properties.phoneno}" />
  <span class="error_msg" data-ng-show="phoneNumberErrorShow">Please enter a valid phone number</span>
</div>
```